# filter an array of object based on a key and get only key value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to filter an array of objects based on a key `selected`. If any of the object has `selected: true`, I want its ID in return. For e.g. below:

Below is the array I have:

```
arr = [
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663a",
    "name": "Southeast Asia",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663f",
    "name": "USA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb6635",
    "name": "MENA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 }
]
```

Logic used to get an `_id` from it:

```
arr.filter(item => {
   if(item.selected) {
     retrun item._id;
   }
});
```

Expected output:

```
[{
  _id: '6311eb86cc42295428bb663a'
}, {
  _id: '6311eb86cc42295428bb6635'
}]
```

But I got the whole array of object in return instead of just _id.

How can I work around this to get only `_id`?

Answer (score 2):

The [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method only filters the input array without changing it's content. The callback you're passing in your code is only expected to return `true` or `false`. To reshape your result you need to use `filter` along with [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663a",
    "name": "Southeast Asia",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663f",
    "name": "USA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb6635",
    "name": "MENA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 }
];

const result = arr.filter(item => item.selected).map(item => ({_id: item._id}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = arr = [
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663a",
    "name": "Southeast Asia",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb663f",
    "name": "USA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
 },
 {
    "_id": "6311eb86cc42295428bb6635",
    "name": "MENA",
    "language": [
        "English"
    ],
    "selected": true
 }
]

let result = data.filter(d => d.selected).map(d => {
      let obj ={}
      obj['_id'] = d._id
      return obj
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map as below :

`let filtered = arr.filter(item => { if(item.selected) { return item._id;}}).map(item => ({_id: item._id}));;`

expected output :

```
 [ { _id: '6311eb86cc42295428bb663a'}, { _id: '6311eb86cc42295428bb6635'}]
```

Comment: Use special code formating

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter returns an array based on your function.

So you have to save that variable like this:

```
let arr2= arr.filter(element => {
    if(element.selected == true)
        return (element)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both filtered and map functions

```html
const filteredArr = arr.filter((element)=>{
    return element.selected != null
})

const reducedArr = filteredArr.map((element) => {
    return {_id:element._id}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**filter + map == reduce**

so this will give you your output:

```
arr.reduce((acc,val)=>{
  if(val.selected){
    acc.push({_id: val._id})
  }
  return acc
},[])
```

Or, most likely you actually need just array of values:

```
arr.reduce((acc,val)=>{
  if(val.selected){
    acc.push(val._id)
  }
  return acc
},[])
```

Comment: You can read about reduce here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Also, reduce will have 1 iteration instead of 2 in case of filter+map